# Concat a Subnet ID reference for azure bastion deployment

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

Can anyone see anything wrong with this? I'm trying to reference a resource in another resource group. I'm deploying a bastion host and want to reference a subnet in another resourcegroup (vnet rg)

This is what I have but it's not working, do I need to reference the subscription? It's badly formatted but tried everything i can thing of :(

```
        "id": "[concat('/','subscriptions','/','parameters('SubscriptionId'),'/','resourceGroups','/',parameters('vnetResourceGroupName'),'/',providers','/','Microsoft.Network','/','virtualNetworks','/','parameters('vnetName'),'/','subnets','/','AzureBastionSubnet'))]"
```

I'm trying to get to this (ish)

```
"id":"/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/subnets/SubnetName"
```

When I try ot use resourceID

```
        "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'), '/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet')]"
```

I get this error:

```
'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current function arguments 
'rg-vnet,Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/,vnet1,/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet'
```

I think its the commas between each segment causing the issue :(
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct format:

"id": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('VNETName'),variables('subnetName'))]"